# Ruby Koans: blocks and arguments (test_blocks_can_take_arguments)

Tags: ruby, block, yield

[Ruby Koans](http://www.rubykoans.com) has the following exercise in about_blocks.rb:

```
  def method_with_block_arguments
    yield("Jim")
  end

  def test_blocks_can_take_arguments
    method_with_block_arguments do |argument|
      assert_equal __, argument
    end
  end
```

I know the answer is **assert_equal "Jim", argument**, but I'm struggling to understand what is happening. Specifically:

- Is `argument` or `assert_equal...` the block?
- What is `yield` doing given that method_with_block_arguments returns "Jim" without `yield`?

Comment: Read this [_The Well-Grounded Rubyist, Second Edition_](http://www.manning.com/black3/) thoroughly..

Comment: @matt Dude, you wrote a book aiming to teach programming and that's your answer? I've done all the koans up to this point and I sorta understand blocks and yield, but I'm having trouble putting it together in this exercise. If you can't sympathize with beginners trying to integrate new concepts, please don't try to be a teacher.

Comment: @matt Friend, I'm not asking to be taught the entire language. I'm asking how specific new concepts are applied in this exercise. I honestly don't understand your attitude, especially since I suspect others have found this exercise challenging. Anyway, I'm sorry if the questions were poorly worded and have tried to clarify them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think some of the above commenters are correct in saying that you currently don't have a very deep understanding of Ruby, but don't let that discourage you. It just takes time to learn. When I was first learning Ruby, the concept of blocks and their syntax did take some time to wrap my head around. Once you get it the syntax is very simple, but you until you reach that point...

Anywho, this is my attempt to help you out. :)

`argument` is a *block variable*. All the stuff between `do` and `end` is the block. `assert_equal` is just a regular method call, nothing to do with blocks.

What `yield` does is the key to understanding how blocks work. What `yield` does it that it "yields" control to the calling function. You may think of it as a callback. When you say "yield" in the middle of a function, you are essentially saying *"in the middle of this function, I want to allow someone else to plug in their code and make decisions about what should happen."* If you use `yield` with no arguments, no data from your method gets passed back to the caller.

In essence, `yield` is a way of "yielding" control to somebody else, in this case the caller of your function.

When you call `yield` with one or more arguments, you are passing data from the your function back up to the caller. So when you say `yield("Jim")` you are handing the String `"Jim"` back to whoever calls `method_with_block_arguments`.

Lastly, you have to understand that in Ruby, methods always return the result of whatever was the last expression in a particular method. That's why you usually don't need an explicit `return` statement.

For instance, this method will return `42`.

```
def foo
  42
end
```

That's because `42` is a valid expression in Ruby. It's just an identity, but it's valid Ruby, so Ruby just says "okay, you said 42 and that's the last thing in this method declaration. So when people call 'foo' they get 42 back".

I hope this helps. I think at this point you should assume that you're still pretty early on in terms of your Ruby learning, but you're on the right track investigating blocks. Once you get them you'll understand one of the most powerful parts of Ruby.

Comment: This answered my question and helped me understand yield, thanks! I'm definitely a Ruby novice. :) (I would vote up but I don't have enough rep yet.)

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Is argument or assert_equal... the block?

No, neither argument nor assert_equal is a block, `argument` is the variable and anything between `do` and `end` is the block. `assert_equal` is a normal method call.

> 2. What is yield doing given that method_with_block_arguments returns "Jim" without yield?

Yield is what makes it special. It calls the block (ie. everything between `do` and `end`) and executes it. "Jim" is the argument to the block.

Here is a gist that I copied from Paul while I was learning ruby. That should help in learning about closures in ruby.